# Error when typing su

Tags: sudo, su

When I run the command `su`, it says:

```
roger@RogerPC:/$ sudo su
sudo: error in /etc/sudo.conf, line 0 while loading plugin `sudoers_policy'
sudo: /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so must be only be writable by owner
sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins
```

Comment: so you ran `chmod` or on some system directories eh? What exactly did you do?

Answer (score 3):

If 'pkexec' package is installed on your machine, please try the below command and enter the password when it prompts.

```
pkexec chmod go-w /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so
```

Or follow the below steps :

Reboot your machine and enter into a recovery mode. Then, drop into a root prompt. And execute below commands :

```
1. mount -o remount,rw /

2. chmod 644 /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so

3. chown root:root /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so

4. reboot
```

It should fix your issue.

Comment: Could do that with live usb